# what is the accuracy of GetLocalTime, Kernel32.dll, windows 7?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get the most accurate (1ms accuracy will be very good) time of day.
I saw this example which is using GetLocalTime:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;    

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SystemTime
{
    public ushort year;
    public ushort month;
    public ushort weekday;
    public ushort day;
    public ushort hour;
    public ushort minute;
    public ushort second;
    public ushort millisecond;
}

public class LibWrap
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern void GetLocalTime([In, Out] SystemTime st);
}

public class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SystemTime st = new SystemTime();
        LibWrap.GetLocalTime(st);
        Console.Write("{0}:{1}:{2}.{3}", st.hour, st.minute, st.second, st.millisecond);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

how much it is accurate?

Comment: why don't you use the `DateTime.Now` property?

Comment: it is not accurate up to 15ms

Comment: You need special hardware to get an absolute clock that accurate.  Usually based on a GPS receiver.  It is still only useful to drivers, Windows is not exactly a real-time operating system in user mode, a thread quantum is 45 msec.  Standard clock resolution is 1/64 second because making it more accurate is pretty pointless.

Comment: @HansPassant and if in my current hardware I will do timeBeginPeriod(1) as CodeInChaos answered?

Comment: The multi-media timer is an incremental timer, not an clock-absolute timer.  And it doesn't do anything to make the clock more accurate.  And it is still subject to kernel threads pre-empting user mode threads.  And it upsets Larry Osterman :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the timer accuracy. Which is 16ms by default(on newer versions of windows), and can be reduced to 1ms with `timeBeginPeriod(1)` (potentially increasing power consumption of the computer).

All "absolute time" functions on windows I know work at timer accuracy. So I expect it to be no better or worse than `DateTime.Now`.

Relative time functions (`StopWatch`, `QueryPerformanceCounter`) have higher accuracy, but give you no meaningful absolute time. They can also suffer from synchronization issues across multiple CPU cores.

But why don't you test it: Write a small program that reads the time, and prints it whenever it increased. Do the same for `DateTime.Now`. And compare.

Comment: thanks. can you show me an example how to reduce the accuracy to 1ms with timeBeginPeriod?

Comment: Just call `timeBeginPeriod(1)`. But note that this has a global effect, and influences timer accuracy in all applications.